# AngularJS Input Directive with buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working to create a directive which will, on focus of an input field, display a set of buttons used to increment or decrement the value in the input.  In this case Imperial units (1/8",1/4",1/2").

The first issue I am running into is that when a button is pressed, the focus comes off of the input and so the buttons are hidden via the directive.

The second issue is I am unsure of exactly how to access the ngModel in order to properly add (or remove) the value of the button pressed.  The main reason for having the directive around the input instead of directly on the input is for formatting where I want the buttons to be placed but if that can be done when tied to the input that would certainly make this directive significantly less hard to make work correctly.

Here is the code I have setup thus far:

Form input:

```
 <measurements>
    <label>
      <span>Length</span>
      <i ng-show="form.length.$dirty && form.length.$error.required" class="error-icon"></i>
      <input type="number" name="length" ng-model="form.length" required placeholder="Length">
    </label>
  </measurements>
```

The directive currently:

```
angular.module('directive.measurements', [])
    .directive('measurements', [function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                transclude: true, 
                templateUrl: 'measurements.html',
                scope: {
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                    scope.focused = false;
                    var input = element.find('input');
                    input.on('focus', function(event) {
                        scope.focused = true;
                        scope.$apply();
                    });
                    input.on('blur', function(event) {
                        scope.focused = false;
                        scope.$apply();
                    });
                    scope.add = function(amt){

                    };
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Finally the template 'measurements.html':

```
<div>
  <span ng-show="focused">
    <button class="button button-small" ng-click="add(.125)">+1/8</button>
    <button class="button button-small" ng-click="add(.25)">+1/4</button> 
    <button class="button button-small" ng-click="add(.5)">+1/2</button>
  </span>
  <span ng-transclude>
  </span>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
After playing around a little bit with the focusing issue I came up with changing the 'blur' event to the following, whether this is best or not I am not sure, but it does work:

```
if (event.relatedTarget === null) {
  input[0].focus();
} else {
  scope.focused = false;
  scope.$apply();
}
```

**Edit 2**
Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6eUgRhUSA8yI1s42j9JD?p=preview

Comment: can you create a demo plunker or jsfiddle for us to play with?

Comment: Added plunker example

Comment: It looks like your directive depends on the `<input>` tag inside your `<measurement>` tags. Why not include the `<input>` tag directly in the directive's template? Why nest other content within the directive? The directive should be self-reliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/x82yv6ZsXhaMUjk0Hdw9?p=preview) is an improvement of your plnkr to make the directive working.

Regarding your issues:

1. Losing focus is handled by comparing `event.targetElement` with buttons from your template.
2. Adding value is achieved with `ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue` (`ngModelCtrl` is obtained with `require`).

small comment

I would not use `transclusion` at all -- instead would use the directive directly on the input element itself.

Give me a shout if more help needed.

### UPDATE

#### How could this be achieved without transclusion?

In the most straightforward way you can use something like [THAT](http://plnkr.co/edit/t4hAHsvT2PJzXKH8lOMV?p=preview) or do it dynamically (look: [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/dMvea1a7ym05b4z7zsYd?p=preview)). Basically you make use of `$compile` service to manually add the buttons' panel to DOM.

Comment: How could this be achieved without transclusion?  I was thinking about avoiding it but couldn't figure out how to add/remove the buttons?  This is a more contrived example of my actual code, which is a page full of these with other validation items as well.

Comment: Ooohh yea i just figured with so many on the page the compile of all of those would slow the page down quite a bit, but that would certainly encapsulate it quite nicely.

Comment: Thought about the performance and therefore proposed the dynamic compilation. For sure, it will be faster than your initial approach with transclusion.

Comment: Scratch my last comment didn't know what you meant by dynamically until i read the second plunkr code.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, glad that could help :-)

Comment: The only quirk I am seeing with my code is that the event.related target comes back null instead of as a "[object HTMLButtonElement]" as shown in your example and I am not sure why that is?

Comment: The other thing I noticed is that it does not respect the tab key then as well... I can open another question and provide my more accurate testing code if you would prefer?